# Jenkins dependencies from sbt dependencies?

Tags: jenkins, sbt

Is it possible to automatically sync Jenkins build dependencies with sbt dependencies? For example, if project B's build.sbt says that project A (which I also wrote) is a dependency of it, can the Jenkins build for project B be made to automatically detect this fact - and detect any other dependencies that may be added or removed to the build.sbt file in future?

Comment: Just to inquire, since I'm facing the same problem right now, how did you end up solving this?

Comment: @ElmarWeber I didn't in the end, I just did it manually.

Comment: Good, then I'm not that far off the common track =) It's a pain in the ass though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ScriptTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin) to write the appropriate code. Or you could write your own plugin and look at [IvyTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IvyTrigger+Plugin) or [Maven Dependency Update trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Dependency+Update+trigger). That might make a good enhancement to the [sbt plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin).